# "it" as object?

Tags: objects, reference, it-its-itself

In a worksheet we had the statement "I love it here. Let's return next year." A student asked what "it" refers to and I'm not exactly sure myself. Is the "it" here a kind of dummy it?

Comment: It's a dummy object inserted because _love_ requires one. This happens with some verbs that refer to emotions but are transitive, like _hate, like, love_, etc.

Comment: @John what would a non-transitive emotional verb be?

Comment: "I worried."
"He pined."

Comment: Although you can add objects with a prepositional phrase: "I worry about dying", "the parrot is pining for the fjords".

Comment: And "worried" can also be transitive by itself: "I worried my mother".

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't "it" represent "the experience of being", or just "being"? I think it is subtly distinct from loving the place in the abstract, which could be for other reasons.

> "I *like* America. Its trade war against China has weakened the Chinese currency, making Chinese goods cheaper for my family in the UK. I don't like it *in* America, though. Guns make me anxious."
>
> "Oh, I got used to the guns: I love it here!"